# Open Reading Frames vs Coding Sequences (CDS), are they different?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, gene

The two terms confuse me for a long time. What is the difference between ORF and CDS. Some people say ORF could contain intron and CDS does not. The wikipedia definition of ORF does not contains intron. Could someone define the two terms and point out their differences? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (mostly) like the definitions given on [this page](http://www.scfbio-iitd.res.in/tutorial/orf.html).

> An ORF is a sequence of DNA that starts with start codon “ATG” (not always) and ends with any of the three termination codons (TAA, TAG, TGA). Depending on the starting point, there are six possible ways (three on forward strand and three on complementary strand) of translating any nucleotide sequence into amino acid sequence according to the genetic code. These are called reading frames.
>
> The Coding Sequence (CDS) is the actual region of DNA that is translated to form proteins. While the ORF may contain introns as well, the CDS refers to those nucleotides (concatenated exons) that can be divided into codons which are actually translated into amino acids by the ribosomal translation machinery.

However, I do not entirely agree with this statement:

> In Prokaryotes the ORF and the CDS are the same.

While it’s true that all CDSs are within ORFs, not all ORFs are CDSs. You can have ORFs that are transcribed as noncoding RNA elements, and ORFs that are not transcribed at all. CDS refers specifically to the ORFs whose post-transcriptional fate is to be translated.

Comment: I just found a post on biostar with the same question and lots of discussions: https://www.biostars.org/p/47022/